# How can you use PyTorch Profiler on SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-debugger

Is there a way to use the PyTorch profiler when using Amazon SageMaker?
Or can we call PyTorch profiler in the profiler config for SageMaker debugger

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below snippet to initiate a Profiler .

```
from sagemaker.pytorch import PyTorch
from sagemaker.debugger import ProfilerConfig, FrameworkProfile
profiler_config = ProfilerConfig(
    framework_profile_params=FrameworkProfile(start_step=1, num_steps=2)
)
```

Then you can pass the `profilfer_config` to the `Pytorch` estimator.

Answer (score 0):

To use the PyTorch vanilla profiler in SageMaker Training jobs:

1. On the SageMaker Estimator turn off the SageMaker built-in profiler (as you'll be using the PT Vanilla profiler): `estimator = PyTorch(..., disable_profiler=True, ...)`
2. In your training script add PT profiler as shown in [this PT Profiler with TensorBoard tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/tensorboard_profiler_tutorial.html).
3. Export the profiling data to SageMaker managed output folder: `on_trace_ready=torch.profiler.tensorboard_trace_handler(f'{args.output_data_dir}/profile')`
4. when the job completes. Start TensorBoard with the S3 location of the output data folder: `estimator.latest_job_tensorboard_artifacts_path()`